# Theano example for solving linear programming

Tags: python, theano, numerical, deep-learning

I have the following problem. Let's say we have `x_{jk}` it is an expression value of gene *j* in a sample *k*. It is the average of expression levels across the cell types *s_{ij}*, weighted by respective proportions *a_{ki}* (*i = 1 ... N*,N is the disease type):

[image]

Generally this can be expressed as matrix form

[image]

What I want to do is to solve this equation

[image]

How can it be done using Theano?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in theano or not do it in theano. The only thing theano can help you with here is the gradient of the euclidean norm, which it can calculate for you, but which is also easy to write by hand. The algorithm to solve the problem needs to be implemented by yourself. Either you write the lagrangian and then solve the dual problem by gradient ascent and projection onto the constraint, or you solve the primal problem directly by gradient descent and projection onto the constraints. You need to program these optimization steps yourself, which is also the case for any other optimization you do in theano.

Comment: can you give simple example?

Comment: I'm sorry, that would take too much time. A lot of this is explained in Boyd's convex optimization book. See also their technical report on proximal operators which can be useful here.

Comment: This is a [QP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) problem not an [LP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). I don't think that it is a wise thing to implement in theano. In general, it is not a good idea to implement any classical optimization problems on your own unless it is your very field of study. Pick a solver [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming#Solvers_and_scripting_.28programming.29_languages)!

Comment: I guess that is a comment for the original post (+1)